# How is Seq unfold implemented

Tags: ocaml

I have a question about how Seq's unfold function is implemented.

I tried creating my own Seq module(My_Seq) to see if I understood how that functionality worked and I can't get my unfold to behave like Seq's unfold function.

Here's my attempt(My_Seq, note I removed all but the necessary functionality)

```
module type My_Seq_Sig =
sig
  type 'a t

  val empty: 'a t
  val iter: ('a -> unit) -> 'a t -> unit
  val unfold : ('b -> ('a * 'b) option) -> 'b -> 'a t
end

module My_Seq:My_Seq_Sig =
struct
  type 'a t = unit -> 'a node
  and
    'a node =
    | Nil
    | Cons of 'a * 'a t

  let empty = fun () -> Nil

  let rec iter f s =
    match s() with
    | Nil -> ()
    | Cons (e, next) -> f e; iter f next

  let rec unfold f e =
    match (f e) with
    | None -> empty
    | Some (e, next) -> fun () -> Cons (e, unfold f next)
end
```

Here's how I'm calling my module My_Seq:

```
let seq =
  let line = ref 0 in
  let filename = print_string "Enter filename: "; read_line() in
  My_Seq.unfold
    (
      fun e ->
        try
          line := !line + 1;
          Some(((string_of_int !line) ^ ": " ^ (input_line e)), e)
        with
        End_of_file
        | _ ->
        print_endline("---Read->" ^ string_of_int (!line - 1) ^ "<-Line(s)---");
        close_in e;
        None
    )
    (open_in filename)

let () =
  seq |> My_Seq.iter print_endline
```

Here's the output from my attempt:

```
Enter filename: datafile
1: This is the first
2: This is the second
3: This is the third
4: This is the fourth
---Read->5<-Line(s)---
5: This is the fifth
```

Now if I use Seq's unfold function:

```
let seq2 =
  let line = ref 0 in
  let filename = print_string "Enter filename: "; read_line() in
  Seq.unfold
    (
      fun e ->
        try
          line := !line + 1;
          Some(((string_of_int !line) ^ ": " ^ (input_line e)), e)
        with
        End_of_file
        | _ ->
        print_endline("---Read->" ^ string_of_int (!line - 1) ^ "<-Line(s)---");
        close_in e;
        None
    )
    (open_in filename)

let () =
  seq2 |> Seq.iter print_endline
```

Here's the output from using Seq's unfold function:

```
Enter filename: datafile
1: This is the first
2: This is the second
3: This is the third
4: This is the fourth
5: This is the fifth
---Read->5<-Line(s)---
```

datafile contents:

```
This is the first
This is the second
This is the third
This is the fourth
This is the fifth
```

You'll note that the outputs differ and I have no idea why. Maybe someone can shed some light on this.

That did it Guest0x0

```
let rec unfold f e =
    fun () ->(
    match (f e) with
    | None -> Nil
    | Some (e, next) -> Cons (e, unfold f next))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference lies in when the last element is computed. In your `unfold`, the last element is computed (in `f e`) when the element *before* it is fetched (via feeding a unit argument somewhere), while the `Stdlib` version computes the last element only when that element itself is fetched.

To make your `unfold` behaves like the `Stdlib` one, notice that both branches of your `unfold` returns a function taking unit as argument. By lifting this argument outside the whole pattern matching, the actual computation of `f e` will then get delayed, leading to the `Stdlib` behavior